# d3js Force Directed Graph - Click on node to popup infobox which read from JSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

I have been working with [Force-Directed Graph](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) but I am still new to D3js and Javascript.

I want to able to click on the node and the infobox popup on the page and print some information about that node (from JSON).

Example of my json file:

```
{"directed": false, "graph": {}, 
"nodes": [{"id": 0, "name":"Ant" , "info":"Small Animal"}, 
{"id": 1 , "name":"Apple" , "info":"Fruit"}, 
{"id": 2 , "name":"Bat" , "info":"Fly Animal"}, 
{"id": 3 , "name":"Boat" , "info":"Vehicle"}, 
{"id": 4 , "name":"Banana" , "info":"Long cute Fruit"}, 
{"id": 5 , "name":"Cat" , "info":"Best Animal"}], 

"links": [{"source": 0, "target": 0 , "weight":1}, {"source": 0, "target": 2, "weight": 0.3}, 
{"source": 0, "target": 5, "weight":0.8}, {"source": 1, "target": 1, "weight":1}, 
{"source": 1, "target": 4, "weight":0.5}, {"source": 2, "target": 2, "weight":1}, 
{"source": 3, "target": 3, "weight":1}, {"source": 4, "target": 4, "weight":1}, 
{"source": 5, "target": 5, "weight":1}], 
"multigraph": false}
```

So when I click on a node. It should popup something like:

```
Name: Ant
Info: Small Animal
Connected to: Bat with 0.3 weight , Cat with 0.8 weight
```

My graph code were pretty much like the example of force-directed that I link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation, it builds your "infobox" using SVG:

```
  var tip;
  node.on("click", function(d){
    if (tip) tip.remove();

    tip  = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x  + "," + d.y + ")");

    var rect = tip.append("rect")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue");

    tip.append("text")
      .text("Name: " + d.name)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("x", 5);

    tip.append("text")
      .text("Info: " + d.info)
      .attr("dy", "2em")
      .attr("x", 5);

    var con = graph.links
      .filter(function(d1){
        return d1.source.id === d.id;
      })
      .map(function(d1){
        return d1.target.name + " with weight " + d1.weight;
      })

    tip.append("text")
      .text("Connected to: " + con.join(","))
      .attr("dy", "3em")
      .attr("x", 5);

    var bbox = tip.node().getBBox();
    rect.attr("width", bbox.width + 5)
        .attr("height", bbox.height + 5)
  });
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
    
d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/15daa79f-7573-11e8-b9d7-1b0997147957", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;
  
  link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.weight * 3; });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  var tip;
  svg.on("click", function(){
    if (tip) tip.remove();
  });
  node.on("click", function(d){
    d3.event.stopPropagation(); 
  
    if (tip) tip.remove();
    
    tip  = svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x  + "," + d.y + ")");
      
    var rect = tip.append("rect")
      .style("fill", "white")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue");
    
    tip.append("text")
      .text("Name: " + d.name)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .attr("x", 5);
      
    tip.append("text")
      .text("Info: " + d.info)
      .attr("dy", "2em")
      .attr("x", 5);

    var con = graph.links
      .filter(function(d1){
        return d1.source.id === d.id;
      })
      .map(function(d1){
        return d1.target.name + " with weight " + d1.weight;
      })
      
    tip.append("text")
      .text("Connected to: " + con.join(","))
      .attr("dy", "3em")
      .attr("x", 5);
    
    var bbox = tip.node().getBBox();
    rect.attr("width", bbox.width + 5)
        .attr("height", bbox.height + 5)
  });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's look really good but when the info show up there is no way to remove it (apart from click other node). Can the infobox disappear when clicking on blank-space?

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mark: When I run this in chrome I get an error: {
  "message": "Uncaught [object ProgressEvent]",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 46,
  "colno": 14
}

Comment: @SethRobertson, fixed.

Comment: @Mark: fixed ? I get on Chrome the same error as Seth Robertson

Comment: This is really helpful! Is it also possible to move the infobox to the side? So it is nog on top of the node. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can add click event on node using `.on('click', function(d){ });` 
For example:

```
node.on("click", function(d){
      console.log(d);
       // here you can access data of node using d.key 
      alert("You clicked on node " + d.name);
    });
```